# SwiftUI - rounded textField

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a textField:

```
TextField("Message...", text: $chatViewModel.composedMessage)
          .frame(height: 30)
          .padding(10)
          .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
          .foregroundColor(Color(red: 237/255, green: 237/255, blue: 237/255))
```

It creates the rounded corner with the correct `foregroundColor` but the text color is also the same as the foregroundColor.

So if I change this:

```
.foregroundColor(Color(red: 237/255, green: 237/255, blue: 237/255))
```

to

```
.foregroundColor(Color.black)
```

It changes the textfield background colour but also the text color, so I can never see what im actually typing in the textField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add file color for RoundedRectangle.

```
.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(Color(red: 237/255, green: 237/255, blue: 237/255))) // Here!!
.foregroundColor(.black)
```

Answer (score 3):

## 2022, SwiftUI 2.0

```
TextField("File Name", text: $fileName)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField("Email", text: $email)
            .textFieldStyle(.plain)
            .frame(height: 40)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .padding()
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:10.0).strokeBorder(Color.gray, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.0)))
                        .padding()
```

Comment: Please consider adding explanation/detail for your answer.